# Unable to test a smart contract on ropsten test network

Tags: solidity, contract-development, erc-20, out-of-gas, failed-transaction

I launch and verify an ERC20 based smart contract on a ropsten test network which allows user to interact with the contract (send eth to it and the contract automatically send token in returns as in selfdrop) but each time I tried testing to confirm the functions of the selfdrop by sending an eth faucet to it, the contract is not interacting writing "fail" and "out of gas".

This is the solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.25;

/**
 * @title Zedd
 */
library SafeMath {

    /**
    * @dev Multiplies two numbers, throws on overflow.
    */
    function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        c = a * b;
        assert(c / a == b);
        return c;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Integer division of two numbers, truncating the quotient.
    */
    function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
        // uint256 c = a / b;
        // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
        return a / b;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Subtracts two numbers, throws on overflow (i.e. if subtrahend is greater than minuend).
    */
    function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
        assert(b <= a);
        return a - b;
    }

    /**
    * @dev Adds two numbers, throws on overflow.
    */
    function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256 c) {
        c = a + b;
        assert(c >= a);
        return c;
    }
}

contract ForeignToken {
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant public returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool);
}

contract ERC20Basic {
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    function balanceOf(address who) public constant returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public constant returns (uint256);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract Zedd is ERC20 {

    using SafeMath for uint256;
    address owner = msg.sender;

    mapping (address => uint256) balances;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) allowed;
    mapping (address => bool) public Claimed; 

    string public constant name = "Zedd";
    string public constant symbol = "ZedM";
    uint public constant decimals = 12;
    uint public deadline = now + 37 * 1 days;
    uint public round2 = now + 32 * 1 days;
    uint public round1 = now + 22 * 1 days;

    uint256 public totalSupply = 300000000e12;
    uint256 public totalDistributed;
    uint256 public constant requestMinimum = 1 ether / 200; // 0.005 Ether
    uint256 public tokensPerEth = 50000e12;


    //here u will write your ether address
    address multisig = 0x478E1dD0fb8aE01bE6F23a052CCAdd3037FF0c9F
    ;


    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

    event Distr(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
    event DistrFinished();

    event Airdrop(address indexed _owner, uint _amount, uint _balance);

    event TokensPerEthUpdated(uint _tokensPerEth);

    event Burn(address indexed burner, uint256 value);

    event Add(uint256 value);

    bool public distributionFinished = false;

    modifier canDistr() {
        require(!distributionFinished);
        _;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    constructor() public {
        uint256 teamFund = 100000000e12;
        owner = msg.sender;
        distr(owner, teamFund);
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        if (newOwner != address(0)) {
            owner = newOwner;
        }
    }

    function finishDistribution() onlyOwner canDistr public returns (bool) {
        distributionFinished = true;
        emit DistrFinished();
        return true;
    }

    function distr(address _to, uint256 _amount) canDistr private returns (bool) {
        totalDistributed = totalDistributed.add(_amount);        
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
        emit Distr(_to, _amount);
        emit Transfer(address(0), _to, _amount);

        return true;
    }

    function Distribute(address _participant, uint _amount) onlyOwner internal {

        require( _amount > 0 );      
        require( totalDistributed < totalSupply );
        balances[_participant] = balances[_participant].add(_amount);
        totalDistributed = totalDistributed.add(_amount);

        if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
            distributionFinished = true;
        }

        // log
        emit Airdrop(_participant, _amount, balances[_participant]);
        emit Transfer(address(0), _participant, _amount);
    }

    function DistributeAirdrop(address _participant, uint _amount) onlyOwner external {        
        Distribute(_participant, _amount);
    }

    function DistributeAirdropMultiple(address[] _addresses, uint _amount) onlyOwner external {        
        for (uint i = 0; i < _addresses.length; i++) Distribute(_addresses[i], _amount);
    }

    function updateTokensPerEth(uint _tokensPerEth) public onlyOwner {        
        tokensPerEth = _tokensPerEth;
        emit TokensPerEthUpdated(_tokensPerEth);
    }

    function () external payable {
        getTokens();
     }

    function getTokens() payable canDistr  public {
        uint256 tokens = 0;
        uint256 bonus = 0;
        uint256 countbonus = 0;
        uint256 bonusCond1 = 1 ether / 10;
        uint256 bonusCond2 = 1 ether;
        uint256 bonusCond3 = 5 ether;

        tokens = tokensPerEth.mul(msg.value) / 1 ether;        
        address investor = msg.sender;

        if (msg.value >= requestMinimum && now < deadline && now < round1 && now < round2) {
            if(msg.value >= bonusCond1 && msg.value < bonusCond2){
                countbonus = tokens * 10 / 100;
            }else if(msg.value >= bonusCond2 && msg.value < bonusCond3){
                countbonus = tokens * 15 / 100;
            }else if(msg.value >= bonusCond3){
                countbonus = tokens * 20 / 100;
            }
        }else if(msg.value >= requestMinimum && now < deadline && now > round1 && now < round2){
            if(msg.value >= bonusCond2 && msg.value < bonusCond3){
                countbonus = tokens * 20 / 100;
            }else if(msg.value >= bonusCond3){
                countbonus = tokens * 20 / 100;
            }
        }else{
            countbonus = 0;
        }

        bonus = tokens + countbonus;

         if(tokens > 0 && msg.value >= requestMinimum){
            if( now >= deadline && now >= round1 && now < round2){
                distr(investor, tokens);
            }else{
                if(msg.value >= bonusCond1){
                    distr(investor, bonus);
                }else{
                    distr(investor, tokens);
                }   
            }
        }else{
            require( msg.value >= requestMinimum );
        }

        if (totalDistributed >= totalSupply) {
            distributionFinished = true;
        }

        //here we will send all wei to your address
        multisig.transfer(msg.value);
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant public returns (uint256) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    modifier onlyPayloadSize(uint size) {
        assert(msg.data.length >= size + 4);
        _;
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyPayloadSize(2 * 32) public returns (bool success) {

        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_amount <= balances[msg.sender]);

        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_amount);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) onlyPayloadSize(3 * 32) public returns (bool success) {

        require(_to != address(0));
        require(_amount <= balances[_from]);
        require(_amount <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

        balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_amount);
        allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_amount);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
        return true;
    }

    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        if (_value != 0 && allowed[msg.sender][_spender] != 0) { return false; }
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant public returns (uint256) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    function getTokenBalance(address tokenAddress, address who) constant public returns (uint){
        ForeignToken t = ForeignToken(tokenAddress);
        uint bal = t.balanceOf(who);
        return bal;
    }

    function withdrawAll() onlyOwner public {
        address myAddress = this;
        uint256 etherBalance = myAddress.balance;
        owner.transfer(etherBalance);
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 _wdamount) onlyOwner public {
        uint256 wantAmount = _wdamount;
        owner.transfer(wantAmount);
    }

    function burn(uint256 _value) onlyOwner public {
        require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
        address burner = msg.sender;
        balances[burner] = balances[burner].sub(_value);
        totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(_value);
        totalDistributed = totalDistributed.sub(_value);
        emit Burn(burner, _value);
    }

    function add(uint256 _value) onlyOwner public {
        uint256 counter = totalSupply.add(_value);
        totalSupply = counter; 
        emit Add(_value);
    }


    function withdrawForeignTokens(address _tokenContract) onlyOwner public returns (bool) {
        ForeignToken token = ForeignToken(_tokenContract);
        uint256 amount = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        return token.transfer(owner, amount);
    }
}
```

This is the link of the response I got when I sent eth to the contract:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe5014c30f16c8e4114c3d3e34317d2e5b78f7ab8fcf2ec9e658c50e354d5873a!

And [this is the response I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jbfI.png)

Comment: Instead of a screen capture, it would be better to post a link to the failed transaction on etherscan so that others can easily look at it.  You could also post the contract's source code and tell us specifically which function you are trying to call, and with what arguments, in order to recieve this error.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen in the transaction details (https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xe5014c30f16c8e4114c3d3e34317d2e5b78f7ab8fcf2ec9e658c50e354d5873a, click "click to see more") you are giving 21000 gas. This is the absolute minimum amount of gas to only send Ether to an address but it does not allow for any computations.

As you are calling a contract which has a `payable` function your Ether transactions triggers the function which includes some computations. The sender of any transaction has to pay for any computation required to process the transaction in contracts. So you have to pay for the computation inside the contract and you don't provide the transaction enough gas to perform those computations.

So just simply give your transaction a bigger gas limit (try with 100000 for example) and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Will do that now and get back to you